# For Loop current item dot notation not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxtjs

Good day, can someone please help me with what I am getting wrong here, I have a for loop for an array of objects and I can access the current object in the for loop using the array name with bracket notation and then the object key by adding the dot notation in the end. However, when I try to access this same value in Axios request right inside the for loop it says cannot access key of undefined;

Check out the code below see the URL value of Axios request

```js
var branches = [{"Key":"QXdpYWthbmRhIEZvb2Rz","Name":"Awiakanda Foods"},{"Key":"VldDIExPR0lTVElDUw","Name":"VWC LOGISTICS"},{"Key":"RXllbWFzdGVycyBMaW1pdGVkIC0gRmVzdGFj","Name":"Eyemasters Limited - Festac"}];

for (let i = 0; i <= this.branches.length; i++) {
      var branch = this.branches[i];
      console.log(branches[i].Key); //logs the key correctly but the axios request below cannot find Key
      await this.$axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: `${apiBase + branch.Key}/${clientUrl + apiRoot}`,
          headers,
        })
          .then(async (result) => {
            if (this.branch.Name === "Awiakanda Foods") {
              await this.$store.dispatch("awiakanda/updateLinks", result.data);
            }})
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    }
```

Comment: `i <= this.branches.length`. Think about that.. What is the last index in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access branches[length] element which is not present. Do not try to access the array out of the bound element.
i < array.length
Correct way is as follows:

```js
 var branches = [{"Key":"QXdpYWthbmRhIEZvb2Rz","Name":"Awiakanda Foods"},{"Key":"VldDIExPR0lTVElDUw","Name":"VWC LOGISTICS"},{"Key":"RXllbWFzdGVycyBMaW1pdGVkIC0gRmVzdGFj","Name":"Eyemasters Limited - Festac"}];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.branches.length; i++) {
          var branch = this.branches[i];
          console.log(branch);
          console.log(branches[i].Key); 
          console.log(branch.Key);
        }
```